# Replace string values in a dataframe based on regex match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python data frame with a column called "accredited
This column should have the data of accreditation: "10/10/2011"
Or put: "Not accredited"
But in most of the cases when isn't accredited the column have some text, like:
"This business is not accredited....."
I want to replace the whole text and just put: "Not accredited"

Now, I wrote a  function:

```
def notAcredited(string):
    if ('Not' in string or 'not' in string):
        return  'Not Accredited'
```

I'm implementing the function with a loop, is possible to do this with the ".apply" method?

```
for i in range(len(df_1000_1500)):
    accreditacion = notAcredited(df_1000_1500['BBBAccreditation'][i])
    if accreditacion == 'Not Accredited':
        df_1000_1500['BBBAccreditation'][i] = accreditacion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the vectorized string method [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods):

```
In [72]: df = pd.DataFrame({'accredited': ['10/10/2011', 'is not accredited']})

In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
          accredited
0         10/10/2011
1  is not accredited

In [74]: df['accredited'] = df['accredited'].str.replace(r'(?i).*not.*', 'not accredited')

In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
       accredited
0      10/10/2011
1  not accredited
```

The first argument passed to `replace`, e.g. `r'(?i).*not.*'`, can be any [regex pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The second can be any regex replacement value -- the same kind string as would be accepted by [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). The `(?i)` in the regex pattern makes the pattern case-insensitive so `not`, `Not`, `NOt`, `NoT`, etc. would all match.

`Series.str.replace` Cythonizes the calls to `re.sub` (which makes it faster than what you could achieve using `apply` since `apply` uses a Python loop.)